# What is the difference between vmlinux and vmlinux.bin?

Tags: linux, kernel, images

What is the difference between vmlinux and vmlinux.bin?

Answer (score 1):

At least [on x86](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/boot/compressed/Makefile#L12), `vmlinux.bin` is

> `vmlinux` stripped of debugging and comments

In this context, “comments” refers to ELF sections: `vmlinux` is an ELF object file, and `vmlinux.bin` is the result of stripping its debugging symbols and sections matching the `.comment` pattern. `vmlinux.bin` is constructed by running

```
objcopy -R .comment -S vmlinux vmlinux.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kitt's post,

**vmlinux**

"vmlinux, the name comes from the fact that "linux" supports virtual memory. It is typically in ELF format, created by linker. This file is needed when debugging kernel. In order to boot linux kernel, vmlinux image has to be transformed into different form based on processor type." (Weng, 2017)

**vmlinux.bin**

"This is binary form of kernel image, which is created by using objdump from vmlinux image." (Weng, 2017)

**Ref**: 
Weng, W. (2017, March 17). Linux Kernel image in different forms | Wenwei’s tech Blog. Weng-Blog. http://weng-blog.com/2017/03/linux-kernel-image/